# Flutter Chopper File Upload API throw NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, chopper

I’m have configure `BLoC` + `Chopper` for my Fluter Project and all `API` working fine till date. Currently, integrating `File` Upload `API` and I'm facing some issue from `Chopper` side and I don't know what it is and how can I solve that.

```
@Post(path: "FILE_UPLOAD_URL")
@multipart
Future<Response<ProfileResponse>> uploadUserProfilePic(
  @Header("Authorization") String token,
  @PartFile('file') List<int> file,
);
```

API Call :

```
await SharedPreferenceHelper.getToken().then(
  (token) async {
    final bytes = (await File(event.file.path).readAsBytes()).toList();
    final file = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes);
    profileResponse =
        await Provider.of<ApiService>(context, listen: false)
            .uploadUserProfilePic(token, bytes);
  },
);
```

It’s throwing `NoSuchMethodError` exception from this method and file (`object_patch.dart`),

```
@patch
@pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
  // TODO(regis): Remove temp constructor identifier 'withInvocation'.
  throw new NoSuchMethodError.withInvocation(this, invocation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did modify this requestConverter in between call,

```
@override
  Request convertRequest(Request request) {
    if (!request.multipart) {
      return super.convertRequest(
        request.replace(
          body: serializers.serializeWith(
            serializers.serializerForType(request.body.runtimeType),
            request.body,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return request;
    }
  }
```

`List<bytes>` did not work for me but `File` path help me out,

```
@Post(
    path: URLS.API_UPLOAD_IMAGE,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/formdata"},
  )
  @multipart
  Future<Response> uploadUserProfilePic(
    @Header("Authorization") String token,
    @PartFile('file') String file,
  );
```

Hope this will help some one.

Answer (score 0):

**This Solution worked for me:**

**Function Call**

```
await _apiService.uploadVendorPhoto(_profileImage!.path);
```

**API**

```
@Post(path: 'apiPath/uploadPhoto', headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/formdata"})
  @multipart
  Future<Response> uploadPhoto(@PartFile('image') String image);
```